# Any to string function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin,

I want to create a method that takes in a function such that the function can be applied on `Any` but returns a string. This is basically a function to do string extraction.

How could I do this? So it will be something like this: Suppose I have 2 models

```
class A{
  val myStirngRef: String
}
```

```
class B{
  val otherStringRef: String
}
```

and then I have a method

```
fun doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(instance: Any, function: (Any) -> String){
   val str = function.call(instance)
}
```

Is this possible in Kotlin or is there type changing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is as easy as [`toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html):

```
fun anyToString(arg: Any): String = arg.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand how you intend to use this function. But supposing the function can be called on any object, and the `function` reference you pass is the getter for the String reference, then you can do this with generics:

```
inline fun <T: Any> doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(instance: T, function: (T) -> String){
    val str = function(instance)
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```
val b = B()
doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(b, B::otherStringRef) 

// or

doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(b) { it.otherStringRef }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) in Kotlin.
So you need to define overloaded variants of this function:

```kotlin
inline fun doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(instance: A, function: A.() -> String) = with(instance, function)
inline fun doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(instance: B, function: B.() -> String) = with(instance, function)
```

Usage:

```kotlin
doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(A()) { myStirngRef }
doSomethingWithEitherAOrBType(B()) { otherStringRef }
```